# jsPDF not working with my jQuery textfield

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Javascript, HTML. I would really appreciate any advice I am trying to get all the input data in my query and display it to pdf that I will be downloading using the button and [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) however my code below is not working

My query TextFields are `name`,`company` and etc. I will really appreciate any advice.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar"><span>jsPDF Tutorial - Form Filling</span></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>

  <script>

    $('#button').click(function() {

        var doc = new jsPDF();

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var company = $('#company').val();
        var department = $('#department').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();

        doc.setFontSize(26);
        doc.setTextColor(92, 76, 76);

        doc.text(23, 81, name);
        doc.text(23, 122, company);
        doc.text(23, 162, department);
        doc.text(23, 202, title);
        doc.save('test.pdf');

    });
   </script>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're `<script>` is inside your `#wrapper`? Place `<script>` below #wrapper near closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you you are a genius! Thank you

Comment: just wondering if you could advice how can I open the downloaded pdf in new tab I tried to use this doc.output('datauristring');        //returns the data uri string
doc.output('datauri');              //opens the data uri in current window
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
but not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap elements correctly (`<script>` tag inside `#wrapper`)

**UPDATED:** [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyJVRZ) check this.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="navbar"><span>jsPDF Tutorial - Form Filling</span></div>
  <div>

    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" id="company"/>
    <input type="text" id="department"/>
    <input type="text" id="title"/>
  </div>

  <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>

  //script here
  <script> 
         ...
  </script>
</body>
```

**script**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var company = $('#company').val();
    var department = $('#department').val();
    var title = $('#title').val();

    doc.setFontSize(11);
    doc.setTextColor(92, 76, 76);

    doc.text(15, 20, "Name:");
    doc.text(40, 20, name);
    doc.text(15, 24, "Company:");
    doc.text(40, 24, company);
    doc.text(15, 28, "Department:");
    doc.text(40, 28, department);
    doc.text(15, 32, "Title:");
    doc.text(40, 32, title);
    doc.save('test.pdf');

});
```

Comment: can you advice me like when I implement it to the textfield which is not in wrapper like a build in textfield and I am just calling its ID? I really appreciate your kindess

Comment: Actually, you can remove the #wrapper id in your `div` its not  that important and just run your code. Btw, Is your textfields dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

earlier its working but I dont know what happen it is not working anymore please see thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
      <script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="navbar"><span>jsPDF Tutorial - Form Filling</span></div>
      <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>

      </div> // should be here

      <script>

        $('#button').click(function() {

            var doc = new jsPDF();
      var chars1 = $('#staffname_1_1').val();

            doc.setFontSize(26);
            doc.setTextColor(92, 76, 76);

            doc.text(23, 81, chars1);

            doc.save('test.pdf');

        });
       </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: but I am using jquery textfield

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is still inside the `<div id="wrapper"></div>`

Comment: Can you show the code of your textfields. Check the edited version of your answer.

Comment: <input id="staffname_1_1_1" name="staffname_1_1_1" type="hidden" value="some" />

Comment: How about if my field is not inside the wrapper because it is jquery?

Comment: why it is `type="hidden"`? Textfields should be `type="text"`.

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to achieve. The use of the wrapper is to include other elements in your html that is not your the data you have to input like `labels` etc.  I have updated the answer in codepen.